# Does Google Cloud Firewall log allows and denies?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver

I cannot seem to find a way to see allowed and denied traffic within my Google Cloud Platform logs.  Is it true the GCP Firewall does not log allowed/denied traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible by [enabling firewall rules logging](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewall-rules-logging). The logging is enabled in individual basis (for each firewall rule one is interested).

Answer (score 3):

From the GCP firewall [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls):

> GCP firewall cannot log as an action. It can only accept or reject a connection. GCP does not collect statistics per rule at this time.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the rules match it goes to the lowest priority default rule which is denies all requests without logging them.

You can create a deny all rule with logging at a priority slightly higher than the default (and lower than all your other rules).

This will show all the requests that got denied. It may also create a lot of logs if you suffer a DOS attack or high traffic.

Something like this

```
  deny_all_with_logging_rules = {
    deny-all-with-logging-rule = {
      description          = "Log all denied requests that bounce of the firewall"
      direction            = "INGRESS"
      action    = deny
      priority  = 9999
      source_ranges        = []
      rules                = []
      enable_logging = {
        include_metadata = true
      }
    },
```

See also this article on getting alerts
https://medium.com/google-cloud/notification-of-firewall-denies-c3476a0ea79b